# TYPO3: How to put TS-config of a page into a config file?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

In the TS-Config of a backend-form I can disable the `doktype` field of said backend form by writing:

```
TCEFORM.pages {
  doktype.disabled=1
}
```

How can I put this into a config file on the server? How can I use this just to certain uid's?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation you find all about integrating TSconfig via a file: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/9.5/en-us/UsingSetting/#setting-default-page-tsconfig

Also, you can use conditions in TSconfig, see: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/9.5/en-us/UsingSetting/Index.html#condition-references

Comment: Thank you i somehow missed the manual completely. But i am not sure how to use the info there. I will work through the manual and where it gets me.